# How to position container inside <p> element w/ text flowing around it?

Tags: html, css, position, css-float

I want to bulid a container that has text in it, is partially positioned outside of the parent element horizontally and fully positioned inside the parent element vertically pushing text away. Something like this:
[Quote positioned on left handside of text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S9RX.jpg)

In order to push text away, this container has to be floated, right? To position the container, I tried 2 ways:

1. absolute positioning (inside a container with relative positioning)
2. relative positioning.

The problem: Absolute positioning will make float completely redundant – the container does no longer push text away. And with relative positioning, **the area that pushes text away will stay in the top left corner** of the parent element. But I want it to "follow" the textbox (again, pls look at the picture above). The closest I have come to what I want is this:

```css
 .wrapperSingleProject {
    padding: 80px 0 80px 0;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    }

    p {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 0.08em;
    line-height: 1.45;
    color: black;
    }

    .quote-div p {
    /* relative positioning */
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    color: blue;
    background-color: #ccc;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 -100px 0 0;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 250px;
    left: 0%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    /* absolute positioning: to view activate .relativeposition as well */
    /*
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    color: green;
    background-color: #ccc;
    float: left;
    top: 300px;
    left: 0%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    */
    }

    .relativeposition {
    /*
    position: relative;
    */
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapperSingleProject">
    
 <div class="relativeposition">
  <div class="quote-div">
   <p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</p>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Is this even possible in vanilla HTML+CSS?
Thanks!

Comment: You can check this - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/shape-outside/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution with just negative `margin-left` on the quote-div.

```css
.wrapperSingleProject {
  padding: 80px 0 80px 0;
  width: 400px; /* made the wrapper div smaller so can see the space on the left side here in the snippet display */
  margin: 0 auto; /* centers the wrapper div on the page */
  position: relative;
}

p {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.08em;
  line-height: 1.45;
  color: black;
}

.quote-div {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: -100px;
  float: left;
}

.quote-div p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperSingleProject">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>

  <div class="relativeposition">
    <div class="quote-div">
      <p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</p>
    </div>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
      et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
      sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is now almost the same as my initial code. What I want though is this: Imagine taking your code above and deleting the first <p>-(copy-text-paragraph) to avoid confusion. Then add a "top: 200px" to the .quote-div. That's its final position. Now the box that displaces text does no longer add up with the .quote-div. How can I make it so they add up? To clarify: The quote (and area of displacement) should not be "hidden" between to paragraphs but move vertically into one. Just like in the img I added in the description. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok now that sounds like a different requirement. Would look into CSS Shapes in that case... I have given you 2 working approaches to the original question, I suggest making a new question for that.

Comment: To me it is the same problem. But thank you for your help! I rephrased the question (because I feel like I did not do a very good job at that here) and posted it again here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57475639/move-floated-area-inside-paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Float the `quote-div` element and set its width to half the width you want the quote paragraph to be. Set it to `position:relative` so the text inside can be positioned absolutely, but the main text still flows around it as expected.

```
.quote-div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

Make the paragraph `position:absolute` and set it twice the width of the `quote-div` container. Only pin it to the top and the right side of the `quote-div` wrapper, so it sticks out the left side, and has its natural height based on the contained text.

```
.quote-div p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%; /* paragraph is twice as wide as its wrapper div */
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Lastly, I used javascript to find the `quote-div`, and the contained paragraph element, and set the height of the div to the height of the paragraph. This is what gives the relative positioned `quote-div` the correct height no matter how much text is in the quote.

```js
// find the quote div element
const quoteDiv = document.querySelector('.quote-div');

if (quoteDiv) {
  // find the p inside
  const quoteDivP = quoteDiv.querySelector('p');
  // make the quote div height equal the height of the paragraph
  quoteDiv.style.height = quoteDivP.clientHeight + 'px';
}
```

```css
.wrapperSingleProject {
  padding: 80px 0 80px 0;
  width: 400px; /* made the wrapper div smaller so can see the space on the left side here in the snippet display */
  margin: 0 auto; /* centers the wrapper div on the page */
  position: relative;
}

p {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.08em;
  line-height: 1.45;
  color: black;
}

.quote-div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}

.quote-div p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200%; /* paragraph is twice as wide as its wrapper div */
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #eee;
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperSingleProject">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna</p>

  <div class="relativeposition">
    <div class="quote-div">
      <p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</p>
    </div>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
      At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
      et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
      sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem
      ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
      sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
      rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: BugsArePeopleToo, thank you so much for the code and the extensive description! I copied your code and tried for a while now to get it running. But in my two browsers (Firefox and Safari), I can't seem to get it to work.  It looks pretty much like in the demo, it's just that the quote does not displace the copy text. It probably is just some silly mistake on my part, so I will keep looking. There is one thing that I would like to rule out though: I found this expression in the JS: ${quoteDivP.clientHeight}px.
Does that mean it uses jQuery? I haven't embedded it yet ...

Comment: No, that is a template string in plain javascript... but I realize that is ES6 syntax... replace "`${quoteDivP.clientHeight}px`" with "quoteDivP.clientHeight + 'px'". Hope that helps! I will change it in the code above accordingly.

Comment: I don't mean to be a pain in the a** but I just realized that your code does not fix the problem I had (or at least I don't think?). The idea was to get the displaced area to "follow" the quote so that the quote would be encapsulated in the copytext. Just like in the img I attached.
I updated the question and the code in case you want to have another look. Thank you for your trouble so far.

Comment: I just posted a new answer... not sure why I didnt think to suggest this first. No JS needed, just some `margin-left` with a negative value.