# Move floated area inside paragraph

Tags: css

I would like to have a quote positioned inside one paragraph

[image: like in this image].

I feel like my code is almost there yet I keep running into this problem: When applying a "top:250px" to ".quote-div p" to move it down into the paragraph, instead of following, the area that is floated (to displace text) stays at the top left corner of its parent element.
Does anyone know a way to fix this? Is this even possible? Thanks!

```css
.wrapperSingleProject {
  padding: 80px 0 80px 0;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.08em;
  line-height: 1.45;
  color: black;
}

.quote-div p {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  color: blue;
  background-color: #ccc;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 -100px 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 250px;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperSingleProject">
  <div class="quote-div">
    <p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</p>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
    et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
    tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
    sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
    no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved using [`shape-outside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside) combined with `float`. More examples here: https://dev.to/afif/float-to-the-bottom-corners-i8l

```css
.wrapperSingleProject {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.08em;
  line-height: 1.45;
}
.quote-div {
  float: left;
  padding-top:200px; /*Distance from top*/
  margin-right:10px;
  /* A rectangular shape offseted by 200px from the top*/
  shape-outside: polygon(0 200px,100% 200px, 100% 100%,0 100%);
}
.quote-div p {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  color: blue;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin:0;
  padding:5px;
  margin-left:-100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperSingleProject">
  <div class="quote-div">
    <p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</p>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
    et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
    </p>
</div>
```